# Workaround for :empty Selector Not Being Updated When Children Added in IE11

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

I have simple css statement I want to apply to some HTML that basically only shows an element when its previous sibling is not empty. The use case is to only show a "Clear" button when a list has items in it.

```
<ul></ul>
<button>Clear</button>

ul:empty + button
{
    display: none;
}
```

The problem is that whenever my javascript inserts a new list item into the list, Chrome appears to work correctly and automatically make the button visible. IE11 however fails to show the Clear button. This JS fiddle illustrates the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/xw4nbnz3/

What is the easiest workaround for this problem to make ie11 work? Preferably staying in CSS only.

Comment: Give this library a show and let us know if it works for this bug: 

http://selectivizr.com/

Just a polyfill

Comment: So the main problem is to hide the empty element?

Comment: Sleek Geek, no the problem is to make the "Clear" button invisible whenever the list is empty, and show it when the list isn't empty.

Comment: Can't you make the button visible when a list item is added and then have it hide itself again when it is clicked?

Comment: Yes, thats possible to do. However, in Chrome and Firefox, the CSS works fine and is a very small and elegant solution that doesn't require any javascript to function. This question is mostly seeking a CSS only solution because it is a little silly to implement a whole javascript solution just for ie11.

Comment: Since this is about a problem that appears when an element is added with JavaScript, it would be most natural to use JavaScript to hide/show the button (by setting a class on it or actually removing/adding the button element). This would also make things work on all browsers ever since IE 4 or so, without even relying on support to `:empty`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pretty sure I'd seen this before, but I can't find the previous question anymore so I'll take a stab at it.

This looks like a typical repaint bug: IE will understand your CSS just fine... if the list starts out with items, and if you write a function to empty the list instead, it will not update the button either. Unfortunately, repaint bugs aren't known for having pure CSS workarounds.

Fortunately, they don't usually need them. Since this only happens when you change the DOM, you can easily work around this within the JS, and it doesn't take very many lines. It looks like removing the list itself first, before inserting the new item, then putting the list back in [resolves this issue whilst not creating any problems in other browsers](http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/xw4nbnz3/2):

```
function AddListItem()
{
    var mylist = document.getElementById("mylist");
    if (!mylist)
        return;

    var parent = mylist.parentElement;
    var button = mylist.nextElementSibling;
    parent.removeChild(mylist);

    var li = document.createElement("li");
    li.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Hello, world!"));
    mylist.appendChild(li);

    parent.insertBefore(mylist, button);
}
```

Tested on IE11 on Windows 7, Windows 8.1, and Windows 10 RTM (build 10240), and Microsoft Edge on Windows 10 RTM. Note that removing the list *after* inserting the item (right before putting it back in) does not work; you will need to remove it first.

Comment: Works like a charm! And +1 for the term "repaint bug". I've never heard it before.

Comment: That's an interesting workaround, but I'm using _React_, and I'm doing the work in the _render()_ method. I don't know how I could remove and re-add the element there. Does anyone have any ideas?

Maybe I could conditionally render it in the first place. I'll post an update if I get it working.

Comment: I've got a workaround that works in _React_.

In my case, I had a css rule that was setting `display: none` on certainl child elements using the `:empty` pseudo-selector. I use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML()` with some variable content.

Instead, I'm now conditionally rendering the child elements, only rendering if the html is not empty.

Technically, this means I'm now not rendering some empty elements that I was before, but since I wanted them hidden anyway, I think it's a reasonable trade-off.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is related to cascaded selectors like the `button` in the selector `ul:empty + button`.

It's safe to use the `:empty` pseudo-class in IE11 when it applies to DOM element itself https://codepen.io/egeneralov/pen/geRQXz.

Comment: I see that your example does work in IE11, but it's not always safe. My case involves an `:empty` pseudo-class on the DOM element itself. I'm also using _React_, which might complicate things further.

Comment: Anyway it would be nice if you could provide an example.

Comment: Unfortunately, it would be quite difficult and time consuming to provide an accurate demo of my situation on codepen. I can describe it, though. Multi-line text box for markdown input. Div element to preview output. Div has CSS setting display:none when :empty. We use remarkable for text -> html and React 15.6.2. The case that triggers the problem is when you have one paragraph of text and you add a character that makes a second paragraph. It seems that when React renders the updated content in the div, it removes the one <p> tag then adds the two new <p> tags. I hope this helps.